# jquery popup load from sql database on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

on button click load `<div class="popup">...<div>` popup window. button have some value.. `ex:(1658)`  popup details load from sql database on button value.. i cant do this.. plz help me..

Here is my codes on index.php

```
<ul id="products">
<li>
<div class="image"><img src="../someimage.jpg"><div>
<div class="name">Samsung 65' Curved LED 4K TV</div>
<div class="cart"><button type="button" onclick="" class="button blue">Add to Cart</button><div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="image"><img src="../someimage.jpg"><div>
<div class="name">Samsung Curved LED 4K TV</div>
<div class="cart"><button type="button" onclick="" class="button blue">Add to Cart</button><div>
</li>

</ul>

<div class="popup">
<div class="popup-image"><img src=""></div>
<div class="popup-name"></div>
<div class="popup-cart">
<a href="#" title="close">Close</a>
<a href="./view-cart" title="view cart">View Cart</a>
<a href="./buy-now" title="buy now">Buy Now</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use ajax method to load the data from database .

Comment: plzz help me for this one

Comment: Can you please elaborate properly what you want in this?? Are you done with storing values in button??

Comment: yes.. button has value like `data-id`